# Designing tables for measures efficiently

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, data-warehouse

I have a fairly good understanding of how to normalize my data for employees, management, locations, etc, but I can't figure out a good way to normalize performance metrics?

```
Datetime | Name | ManagerID | LocationID | ... | Surveys | Rating | Interactions | Duration
```

Should each measure be a separate column on the **same** table?

How do you keep track of targets which may change frequently (monthly)? Is the target for each metric also a column (this can't be or it would repeat constantly for each data and employee).

Some measures are 'required' and others are just additional information. is there a way to separate the required measures into their own table? I would need to report on the required metrics ultimately, but have access to the 'non-required' metrics to drill down.

I can't seem to find any best practices. I am dealing with measures which vary per project and not all measures are required, and some have frequent target changes so it is difficult to assess goal attainment (actual/target). Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: See [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: To expand on @CL.'s comment, the rules of normalization are the same across the board. I wouldn't search for best practices for storing performance metrics - go back to basics, think of the things you're trying to model in a conceptual manner, sketch out a conceptual model, then move on to a logical model, and work through the normalization process. If you're still stuck on some points, edit this and include more detail - a logical model or partial schema diagram might be very helpful. The description of the metrics and the things they're related to is currently quite vague.